# Can a mathematical object “inherit” properties?

Tags: word-usage

I have a mathematical object A and a mathematical object B, which is defined in terms of A. It is easy to see that B has some of the properites that A has.

Can I say “B inherits the properties a, b and c from A”? If not, which word instead of “inherit“ should be used?

Comment: How did B acquire the properties it shares with A? Did it receive them in some way from A? *Inherit* would suggest that.

Comment: I think it depends on _how_ B is defined _in terms of A_. If B lives on a subuniverse of A, for example, then certainly one can say B inherits some properties of A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common locution when object B is a subset of object A and itself belongs to the same (dare I say) category as A.  From *[Spectral Theory and Quantum Mechanics](https://books.google.com/books?id=cbJGAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA567&lpg=PA567&dq=%22subgroup%20inherits%22&source=bl&ots=UvH6JStQMa&sig=6dIbUofU5yi-8OAz9jx7VbwH5Eg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBGoVChMIz8muh8yZyQIViHE-Ch2dPwpe#v=onepage&q=%22subgroup%20inherits%22&f=false)* by V Moretti:

> An (embedded) submanifold G' ⊂ G in a Lie group that is also a
>   subgroup **inherits** a Lie group structure from G.

Comment: Thanks! Funny that I'm actually working with Lie groups, as well.

Comment: This answer is especially impressive given that you have no activity on SE math sites and (forgive me if I'm wrong) probably have only a vague idea of what a Lie group is. (Or maybe you just don't know about the math sites.)

Comment: @MattSamuel Please don't be impressed.  None of my professors in either of the two math programs I attended ever was.  And rightly so.  I know what a Lie group is, and the reason I chose the quote is that I think the explanation allows people who passed high school maths to understand the concept of inheritance without having even a vague idea of what a Lie group is.  So it would be a small fraud to let you infer that I  was a mathematical naif, but a larger fraud to imply that I could participate on the math sites.  Age has dulled my ability to learn or impart anything useful.

Comment: @deadrat I understand that. I've seen several examples of people who once knew quite a bit of math but forgot most of the details over time because they ended up doing something else. I actually got a job where the only math involved is financial math, which has basically nothing to do with any of my advanced education. The math sites are helping me stay in the loop. (I see you mentioned categories in your answer, I guess that should've been a giveaway that you were "in the know.")

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes, I'm reduced to making sly puns.  In some ways I'm lucky.  I was smart enough to see the beauty, but dumb enough to force me into a field where I could make a living.